# Require file on runtime & unit test issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, requirejs, amd

I use `require.js` to load files at runtime  like following
**This is working as expected** when I run the file in the right context(I mean when the call is coming from the right path.)

**module1.js**

```
define(["otherModule"], function(otherModule) {
 working!!!
....
```

Now I want to create some unit test to this file (module1) from 
other context (from folder of tests which is found in diffrent location in the project) and I get error

```
require.js:145 Uncaught Error: Script error for: otherModule
```

Since it tries to run the get on this path during the **Unit Test**
which is located in diffrent project structure ...

**https://app/path1/path2/path3/otherModule.js**

And in **runtime** which works (from different context) it find it in the path

**https://app/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/otherModule.js**

There is additional path4 & path5 in the request that works,
How should I solve it to work on both cases (UT/Runtime) ?

http://requirejs.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to get it working by applying a RequireJS configuration file, so that the module name is abstracted from its path:

E.g. in the test context, call something like this as initialization step:

```
  require.config({
    baseUrl: "/path1/path2/path3"
  });
```

Alternatively, you can also remap single modules like so (this can also be used to inject a different implementation of a specific module for testing etc.):

```
  require.config({
    paths: {
        "otherModule": "/path1/path2/path3/otherModule"
    }
  });
```

See here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config

Comment: Thanks but can you elborate with example in my context what does it mean the "module name is abstracted from its path."  and how it suggested to do it... the example in the link is too general, Thanks again for the support!

Comment: @RaynD I have added an example, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks , where should I put the the first suggestions and the second ? for the first do you mean before the define  of the unit test?

Comment: and the second what does it means remap single module ? create new mapper module ?

Comment: @RaynD In your test setup routine, *not* in the `module1.js` file. Where and how depends on your unit test framework, so I can't be more specific.

Comment: Thanks and for the second example where should I put it ?

Comment: @RaynD With remap I mean that you can provide a different implementation. For instance, you may have a module `x` which does a server call and returns some data from that, but for the unit test you code a mock implementation which returns static data without calling the server, thus making the test independent from external resources, more robust in general and faster on top. The code under test does not have to be changed but gets a different implementation of the module `x` when under test.

Comment: Can you please provide some referance for the second options , it will be great if you can provide some link to example.Thanks 1+

Comment: @RaynD This blog post may help you: https://bocoup.com/weblog/effective-unit-testing-with-amd